# How to execute stored procedures with parameters in VB.NET

Tags: oracle, vb.net, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm using PL/SQL and VB.Net to connect to the Oracle database (using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client packages). I don't know how to call stored procedures with parameters from the Oracle database in VB.

For example, my procedure code is:

```sql
    Create or replace PROCEDURE sproc_with_parameters (param NUMBER) AS
    BEGIN
       dbms.output_put.line('param')
    END;
```

My VB.Net code to call that procedure is:

```vb
        Dim rvConn As OracleConnection
        Dim rvCmd As New OracleCommand
        rvConn = CreateConnection()       
        rvCmd.Connection = rvConn
        Try
            rvConn.Open()
            Dim param As New OracleParameter
            param.ParameterName = "@param"
            param.Value = InputBox("Please enter a number")
            param.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32

            rvCmd.CommandText = "sproc_with_parameters"
            rvCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            rvCmd.Parameters.Add(param)

            Dim reader As OracleDataReader = rvCmd.ExecuteReader()

            MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(0))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            rvConn.Close()
        End Try
```

I always got the error of "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement" as I executed the code in VB

Comment: Try using CommandType.StoredProcedure instead of CommandType.Text

Comment: @rgorr By the way, are there any ways to call a stored function directly from VB.net (like CommandType.StoredProcedure for stored procedures)?